# Difference between pulling an image and loading it from tar file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a system which uses docker compose.

example docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  base:
    container_name: base
    image: <hub host>/base
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: BaseDockerfile
    environment: 
      - PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    volumes:
      - data:/volumes/data/
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: "postgres:latest"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Now, I use this docker-compose file in two different ways - Online and Offline.

In the online mode I run `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose push` then ssh to the server I want to deploy it and pull the images and run (`docker-compose pull && docker-compose up`).

In the offline method I run `docker-compose build` (same as first one) and then `docker save` each image to a .tar file then load it using the `docker load -i <file name>` method, then run `docker-compose up`

For some reason I get an error (relating to numpy package missfit) in the offline method but not in the server.

I thought there shouldn't be any difference between the methods because they both build the same images and run the containers with the same parameters (that are defined in the docker-compose file).

I tried docker `system prune && docker volume prune` in all machines that were related to make sure its not a caching issue.

Any ideas as to what the differences between the two methods could be?

EDIT:
Saving dockers:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for image in $docker_hub/base redis postgres
do
    echo "Saving $image"
    docker save $image | gzip > $directory/${image//$docker_hub}.tar.gz
done
```

image loading:

```
print "Loading images"
for file in ./*.tar.gz
do
    echo "Loading file: "$file
    docker load -i $file
done
```

The error I have binary file related:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1945, in to_parquet
    compression=compression, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py", line 256, in to_parquet
    impl = get_engine(engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py", line 25, in get_engine
    return FastParquetImpl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py", line 180, in __init__
    import fastparquet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastparquet/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .core import read_thrift
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastparquet/core.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import encoding
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastparquet/encoding.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .speedups import unpack_byte_array
  File "__init__.pxd", line 861, in init fastparquet.speedups
ValueError: numpy.ufunc has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 192, got 216
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error ?

Comment: Could you also share the exact `docker save` and `docker load` commands?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: See edit. I know think that it is somehow cache related because on a new server I was able to reproduce the issue. I still dont understand why deleting the images and pruning the system and the volumes left any trace of cache.

Comment: @NotSoShabby `docker system prune` does not remove tagged images or the layers used to create them.

Comment: I also ran 'docker rmi $(docker images -q)' and made sure there are no images. I really think there's a caching issue there. maybe in the docker server (that doesnt recognizes that some steps had changes - thus not uploading them)